# How to enable wordWrap in showTextDocument VSCode API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently developing a VSCode extension that involves the task of opening a document and populating text to it.

extension.ts

```js
...

vscode.workspace
  .openTextDocument({
    content
    language: document.languageId,
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, {
      viewColumn: vscode.ViewColumn.Beside, // Editor column to show the text document panel in.
      preserveFocus: true, // new text document panel will not take focus
    });
  });

...
```

Sample content:

```
The code snippet is implementing the bubble sort algorithm. Bubble sort is a simple sorting algorithm that repeatedly steps through the list, compares adjacent elements, and swaps them if they are in the wrong order. This process is repeated until the list is sorted.

In the given code, the function `bubble_sort` takes an array `arr` as input and sorts it in ascending order. The outer loop iterates `n` times, where `n` is the length of the array. This ensures that each element is compared with all other elements.

The inner loop iterates from 0 to `n-i-1`, where `i` is the current iteration of the outer loop. This loop compares adjacent elements and swaps them if they are in the wrong order. The largest element in each iteration "bubbles" up to the end of the array.

After the sorting process is complete, the sorted array is printed using the `print` statement.

In the sample usage, the `numbers` list is initialized with some values. The `bubble_sort` function is then called with `numbers` as the argument, which sorts the list in ascending order. Finally, the sorted list is printed, resulting in the output `[1, 2, 5, 8, 12]`.
```

I want to enable word wrap in this content/document or break the words when the content goes out of the window.

How to do this? Thanks.

Edit:
I have tried executing "editor.action.toggleWordWrap" command as suggested in the comments, but give the same output.

extension.ts

```
...

vscode.workspace
  .openTextDocument({
    content
    language: document.languageId,
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, {
      viewColumn: vscode.ViewColumn.Beside, // Editor column to show the text document panel in.
      preserveFocus: true, // new text document panel will not take focus
    }).then(() => {
      vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.toggleWordWrap");
    });
  });

...
```

Comment: can you not just wait for `showTextDocument` to resolve, and then call `executeCommand("editor.action.toggleWordWrap")` ?